# Vertically and horizontally align text in a fieldset

Tags: php, html, css

I'm sure this question has been asked so many times its just not funny but having searched I can't find a solution that fixes my problem just right.

I have several fieldsets on a php page, the content of each one will be a block of text taken from a database. I want to align the text inside the fieldset both vertically and horizontally. The horizontal part is simple with text-align obviously but the vertical alignment is not so simple.

The resulting HTML markup:

```
    <div class="s_container3">
<a href="custom.php?page=19">
    <fieldset class="services_title2">
        Some Short Text
    </fieldset>
</a>
<a href="custom.php?page=18">
    <fieldset class="services_title2">
        More Short Text
    </fieldset>
</a>
<a href="custom.php?page=20">
    <fieldset class="services_title2">
        Some long text that spills onto the second line
    </fieldset>
</a>
<a href="custom.php?page=21">
    <fieldset class="services_title2">
        More short text again
    </fieldset>
</a>
<span class="stretch"></span>
</div>
```

Below is a link to a jsfiddle I was playing with, it has all extra unrelated CSS stripped out to make sure I didn't have a conflict elsewhere.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2VzFJ/2/)

You can see that the text just sticks to the top of the fieldset. I have tried putting an inner div container and everything else under the sun but I've been staring at this problem for so long it just isn't making sense to me anymore so I'm probably missing a simple solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm open to any approach that'll move the text!

If anymore information is needed just ask!

Thanks in advance

Comment: The vertical-align property only works on elements that have the display properties of inline* or table-cell.  Are you certain that none of the related links over on the side are helpful?   `------>`

Comment: Like I said above I'm so burned out from reading over the code I'm likely missing the obvious solution, so I apologize if I'm insulting anyone's intelligence here but I have gone through as many of the questions as I could and I have even tried to use their solutions but no luck. =( I just need some fresh perspective/ideas I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set line height to your fieldset class, so:

```
      html, body { 
height:100%; 
}

        div { 
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto; 
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px; 
}

        div.s_container3 { 
width:570px; 
text-align:justify; 
}
fieldset.services_title2 { 
    border:none; 
    font-size:1.3em; 
    width:215px; 
    min-height:45px; 
    vertical-align:middle; 
    text-align:center; 
    color:#ffffff; 
    background-color:#1c86b5; 
    margin-top:10px; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    display:inline; 
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px; 
    line-height: 45px;
    }

        .stretch { 
width:100%; 
display:inline-block; 
font-size:0; 
line-height:0; 
}
        a { 
text-decoration:none; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5H6Lf/

Comment: Thanks a lot, adding line-height and tweaking both it and the min-height value got me a good result, figured it would be one simple thing I was missing. Just a further request though @maurelio79, I marked it correct though already as you did answer my original question. I wonder if you could suggest a way of evening out the sizing of the fieldsets, although the text is where I need it to be, now the two different sizes of fieldsets are noticeably different.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand what you mean? Are you speking about fieldset height?